# How to support support dark mode for existing swift app iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, plist, ios-darkmode

I am using Xcode version 11.3.1 and we have not supported the dark mode feature in the latest build. while checking the dark mode in iOS13, all the texts are not visible. It’s working in light mode. But I need to support dark mode as well.

While checking in the dark mode issue, I found solution like below to set the light mode for entire app even if the user select the dark mode:

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
```

But some of them mentioned, if we set this UIUserInterfaceStyle in plist, it will not allow placing the submit the app to App Store.

**My question is, I want to support dark mode and I want to submit the app into App Store as well.**

or

**I need to support only light mode and I want to submit the app into the app store as well.**

Note: I am using the app delegate not using SwiftUI.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you don't set `UIUserInterfaceStyle` on `info.plist` then the App automatically enables dark mode depends on the system. If the system runs with dark mode then the app will start with dark mode.

But to show all the texts or other things you have to use the system color as the background and also for texts. OR you can use a custom color for dark mode or light mode.

Comment: Thanks, @Faysal. If I set the only light mode in plist and is it affected by placing the app to the app store? I

Comment: It should be pass because many apps still not support dark mode features. It's better you can try to submit a version with fixed Interface style.

Comment: @HarikarthickK you should support both modes unless your app has a very good reason to do not do so.

Comment: @HarikarthickK You can use dynamic colors. They will be automatically updated when the device's mode changes. For example you can set your text color to the new dynamic UIColor `.label` it will be black or white depending on the mode chosen by the user. If you need a color to the background you can use `.systemBackground` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/3173140-systembackground

Comment: Thanks Leo. Is there any example for setting dynamci color?

Comment: From assets.xcassets you can create a custom color for your app. In both mode, you can set what the color is being used in different mode.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the images in my question, please check what should i select instead of black color.

Comment: default color is OK for the label. You need to update the parent view of the label.

Comment: In my app, some of the color codes are received from the web service based on the user slecttion in web portal and some of the text set in programmatically and some of the text are set in UI storyborad. I think it takes time to change.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed: Is there a way to use the System Color for texts in the storyboards for Label, Textfields etc?

Answer (score 2):

To make your app look the same in the dark mode as well and it does not hinder the existing UI of the app you can use this line of code in

```
info.plist <key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
```

In this way your app will only will support only the light mode.